# In Rails, what's the right way to reference my route as listed by "rake:routes"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm confused about routes and Rails 5.  I have this in my controller ...

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @my_event.save
    puts "saved successfully."
    format.html { redirect_to my_events, notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
```

as you can see from "rake routes", "my_events" is defined.

```
macbook1:myproject nataliab$ rake routes
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                            Controller#Action
    ...
    my_events GET    /my_events(.:format)          my_events#index
```

Yet when the above runs, I get the error

```
undefined local variable or method `my_events' for #<MyEventsController:0x007fa3b9479348>
```

What's the right way to reference my route from my controller?

Comment: the helpers have to end with either `_path` or `_url` (`_url` adds the hostname). Try using `my_events_path`

Comment: Thanks adding "_path" worked.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try swapping my_events for @my_event.

```
format.html { redirect_to @my_event, notice: 'Saved successfully.' }
```